# Override max-width margins of parent container?

Tags: html, css

I am setting up a max-width on my site's main container so that it doesn't appear comically wide on large screens, resulting in left and right margins on the main container. One piece of content we have is dynamically generated and could potentially be very wide. On large screens it's currently pushed over by the main containers left margin, aligning it with the rest of the content of the page, but I would like for it to align with the true left edge of the body instead of the edge of the container.

This picture shows some regular content with the expected margins, and my large content (a tournament bracket) overflowing off the right edge of the screen. I'd like to shift it to the very left.
[image: Large content for a small container]

Is there any way to do this without having to move it outside of the container? Additionally, is there an easy way to make it only do this when it would otherwise be larger than the main container (or even better, only when it would go off the right edge of the screen)?

Comment: what have you tried so far?. Show us you code, as explicit as possible, and we may, then, try to help you.

Comment: I don't even know if this is possible, let alone what to try to do for it. The only thing I'm aware of is negative margins, but I only know how to hardcode that, not how to make it responsive or to make it equal to the negative of the main container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Here's a generic solution that keeps the child element in the document flow:

```
child {
  width: 100vw;
  position: relative;
  left: calc(-50vw + 50%);
}
```

We set the `width` of the child element to fill the entire viewport width, then we make it meet the edge of the screen by moving it to the `left` by a distance of half the viewport, minus 50% of the parent element's width.

#### Demo:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.parent {
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 1rem;
  position: relative;
  background-color: darkgrey;
}

.child {
  width: 100vw;
  position: relative;
  left: calc(-50vw + 50%);
  height: 100px;
  border: 3px solid red;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  Pre
  <div class="child">Child</div>
  Post
</div>
```

Browser support for [vw](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units) and for [calc()](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc) can generally be seen as IE9 and newer.

**Note:** This assumes the box model is set to [`border-box`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing). Without `border-box`, you would also have to subtract paddings and borders, making this solution a mess.

**Note:** It is encouraged to hide horizontal overflow of your scrolling container, as certain browsers may choose to display a horizontal scrollbar despite there being no overflow.

Comment: After playing around a bit with the other, simpler solution, this one ends up playing more nicely with other content on my page since it uses the `position: relative`

Comment: @cebo glad that it helped you :)

Answer (score 1):

You can `position` it `relative` so that you will be able to use `left` property and position it to left end , using appropriate values ( can't say which value will work as you haven't provided code )

If you want to position that when it is larger then you can apply a **JS function** and call it to measure width ( spanning that is `offsetWidth`) of your element .

If it's value exceeds a certain value then
apply `style.position = "relative"` ,
`style.left = "somePreferredvalues"`
else apply `style.position = "static"`

I will be sure about the `position` being `absolute` or `relative` if you provided your code . So try with both once

Comment: `position: relative` didn't do anything for me since I didn't know what to make the left offset relative to the parent, but based on this answer, I found that `position: absolute; left: 0` worked as I wanted it, and I was able to set it up in my JS to only apply that style based on the number of columns in the custom content.

Comment: Can you share the JS code as it will help me to apply by your method

Comment: I am using React so the page is already fully constructed in javascript. That custom section is also entirely created via javascript, so I simply put these styles directly into those elements during creation based on the number of columns which I know in advance.